# Retrieve data from json output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, extract, stringify

I'm currently working on an application that allows the user to create flowchart-like model by dragging and dropping elements from the toolbox on to the container and assigning properties to these elements. At the end, when the user decides to <kbd>Save</kbd> the model, a Json output of the model will be displayed in the textarea as shown.

Now, I need to re-generate/re-create the same model from this Json output. To do this intended task, I need to extract each and every bit of information that I've saved in the Json output. Any suggestions on how I can extract data from Json output will be welcomed.

**Interface with Generated Json**

[image: Interface]

**Example Json format**

[image: Json Output]

From this if I need to get individual data such as

- id (*Example: 1*)
- class (*Example: streamdrop ui-draggable*)
- position:top (*Example: 108.21181556762696*)

so that I can create these elements with the same data(id, class, position,etc.), how can I retrieve these?

**Code that saves the model in Json format**

```
function saveFlowchart(){
    var nodes = [];
    var matches = [];
    var totalElementCount=0;
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("container").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++)
    {
        matches.push(searchEles[i]);
        var idOfEl = searchEles[i].id;
        totalElementCount=idOfEl;

        if(searchEles[i].id !=null || searchEles[i].id !="")
        {
            var $element = $("#" + searchEles[i].id);
            var dropElem = $("#" + searchEles[i].id).attr('class');

            var position = $element.position();

            finalArray[i] = [];

            var elId = parseInt(idOfEl);

            if (dropElem=="streamdrop ui-draggable")
            {
                finalArray[idOfEl-1][0]= {id:idOfEl};
                finalArray[idOfEl-1][1]= {class:dropElem};
                position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
                position.right = position.left + $element.width();
                finalArray[idOfEl-1][2]= {position:[{top:position.top,left:position.left,bottom:position.bottom,right:position.right}]};
                for(var count=0;count<100;count++)
                {
                    if(createdImportStreamArray[count][0]==idOfEl)
                    {
                        finalArray[elId-1][3]=  {predefinedStream:createdImportStreamArray[count][1]}; //Selected Stream from Predefined Streams
                        finalArray[elId-1][4]= {name:createdImportStreamArray[count][2]}; //asName
                        //alert("createdImportStreamArray[count][0]==elId\n"+count);
                    }
                    else if(createdExportStreamArray[count][0]==idOfEl)
                    {
                        finalArray[elId-1][3]= {predefinedStream:createdExportStreamArray[count][1]}; //Selected Stream from Predefined Streams
                        finalArray[elId-1][4]= {name:createdExportStreamArray[count][2]}; //asName
                    }
                    else if(createdDefinedStreamArray[count][0]==idOfEl)
                    {
                        finalArray[elId-1][3]= {name:createdDefinedStreamArray[count][1]}; //Stream Name
                        finalArray[elId-1][4]= {numberOfAttributes:createdDefinedStreamArray[count][4]-1}; //Number of Attributes
                        var attrNum = createdDefinedStreamArray[count][4];
                        for(var f=0;f<attrNum;f++)
                        {
                            //Todo Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
                            //finalArray[elId-1][5]={attribute:[{attributeName:createdDefinedStreamArray[count][2][f][0],attributeType:createdDefinedStreamArray[count][2][f][1]}]};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (dropElem=="wstreamdrop ui-draggable")
            {
                finalArray[elId-1][0]= {id:idOfEl};
                finalArray[elId-1][1]= {class:dropElem};
                position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
                position.right = position.left + $element.width();
                finalArray[elId-1][2]= {position:[{top:position.top,left:position.left,bottom:position.bottom,right:position.right}]};

                finalArray[elId-1][3]= {windowName:createdWindowStreamArray[elId][1]};
                finalArray[elId-1][4]= {selectedStream:[{index:createdWindowStreamArray[elId][2],name:createdWindowStreamArray[elId][3]}]};
                for(var af=0;af<createdWindowStreamArray[elId][4].length;af++)
                {
                    //Todo Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
                    //finalArray[elId-1][5]={attributes:[{name:createdWindowStreamArray[elId][4][af][0],type:createdWindowStreamArray[elId][4][af][0]}]};
                }
            }

            else if (dropElem=="squerydrop ui-draggable")
            {
                finalArray[idOfEl-1][0]= {id:idOfEl};
                finalArray[idOfEl-1][1]= {class:dropElem};
                position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
                position.right = position.left + $element.width();
                finalArray[idOfEl-1][2]= {position:[{top:position.top,left:position.left,bottom:position.bottom,right:position.right}]};
                finalArray[elId-1][3]= {queryName:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][1]};
                finalArray[elId-1][4] ={fromStream:[{index:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][2][0],name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][2][1]}]};
                var arrlen = createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4].length;
                alert("squery attr array len: "+arrlen);
                finalArray[elId-1][5]= {filter:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][3]};
                for(var ct=0;ct<createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4].length;ct++)
                {
                    finalArray[elId-1][6]= {attributes:[{name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4][ct][0],type:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4][ct][1]}]};
                }

                finalArray[elId-1][7] ={intoStream:[{index:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][5][0],name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][5][1]}]};
            }

        else if (dropElem=="wquerydrop ui-draggable")
            {
             //Continues with other else-if statements in the above same
             manner
        }

    }

    var connections = [];
    $.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
        connections.push({
            connectionId: connection.id,
            pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
            pageTargetId: connection.targetId
        });
    });

    var flowChart = {};
    flowChart.elements =finalArray;
    flowChart.connections = connections;

    var flowChartJson = JSON.stringify(flowChart);
    //console.log(flowChartJson);

    $('#jsonOutput').val(flowChartJson);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use `JSON.parse()` and loop through the array to get the data.

```
var objFromJson = JSON.parse(data);

objFromJson.elements.forEach(function(element) {

    var id = element.id;
    var classes = element.class;
    var positionTop = element.position.top

});
```

Also i would suggest to change the structure of your json to not have so many nested arrays and use more objects to make it easier to assign them to variables

Something like this.

```
{
   elements:[
      {
         id:"218931",
         class:"this that",
         position:{
            top:"2321312312",
            bottom:"2312312312"
         }
      },
      {
         id:"218931",
         class:"this that",
         position:{
            top:"2321312312",
            bottom:"2312312312"
         }
      },
      {
         id:"218931",
         class:"this that",
         position:{
            top:"2321312312",
            bottom:"2312312312"
         }
      }

   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll change mine to the above and try this again. But when I just tried running the above `.parse()` I got [this](https://s5.postimg.org/9pqqtpas7/sjk.png) error. Would love to know why it didn't work on the existing format?

Comment: The code i wrote assumes a object for position yours is currently an array.

Comment: So the above will hold all the info in the form of objects?

Comment: That is just a example how you append those to the DOM is up to you. Again i said your json output has to many arrays which makes it annoying to get there values because you must also loop through those array and find the key that matches so you can get the index of it.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. I'll change this and try it again